# Code Coverage report is overwrting if i run multiple tests (Integration & UnitTesting) for the same project

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

I have a project configured in Bamboo and i have two modules Automation & Build.
If i run sonar analysis for any module, the report is overwriting in sonarqube UI, might be because those are under same project.
Even i have given Dsonar.projectName differently for each module.

It would be great if anyone can help in providing the solution for this.

Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the module base directory.

```
ProjectA
  |---module1
  |---module2

sonar.modules=module1, module2
module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=module1
module2.sonar.projectBaseDir=module2
```